# How to generate hmac in binary in Python and convert it into base64

Tags: python, python-3.x, authentication, hmac, hashlib

I have the following code in bash and I want to convert it in Python.

```
#!/bin/bash
username="USERNAME"
apiKey='KEY'
date=`env LANG="en_US.UTF-8" date -u "+%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT"`
password=`echo -n "$date" | openssl dgst -sha1 -hmac $apiKey -binary | openssl enc -base64`
curl -i --url "YOUR API HERE" \
-X "POST" \
-H "Date:$date" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-u "$username:$password" \
-d'{
    "urls": [
        "YOUR URL HERE"
            ]
}'
```

I have rewritten most of the code in Python but I am having trouble in implementing the following line
password=`echo -n "$date" | openssl dgst -sha1 -hmac $apiKey -binary | openssl enc -base64`

My current python code is as follows

```
import time
import requests
import base64

username = "Username"
apiKey = 'KEY'
date = time.strftime('%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT', time.gmtime())

hmac1 = hmac.new(key=apiKey.encode(), msg=date.encode(), digestmod="sha1")
message_digest1 = hmac1.hexdigest()

headers = {
    "Date": date,
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
}
data = {
    "urls": [
        "YOUR URL HERE"
            ]
}
url = 'YOUR API HERE'
response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data, auth = (username, message_digest1))

print(response.headers)
print(response.text)`
```

I know the answer involves using hmac and hashlib library but none of what I have tried has worked. Also does the -u flag in curl translate to auth in python. Can anyone help

Comment: Both codes use different HMAC keys (`KEY` vs `Key`) and different encodings for the result (Base64 vs hex).

Comment: That was a typo mistake for apiKey. I have corrected the mistake. For different encodings let me check how to encode in base64 in python